# KVL with current source question

Tags: circuit-analysis

What is wrong with the calculations below?

[image]

*This is not homework.

Comment: R2 is not 0 , but is an infinite R regulated current source and arrow is shown negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use KCL at the top and bottom nodes. Assuming there is nothing connected at a and b this should be easy.

You can't write a KVL equation with a voltage term for a current source, because the voltage across a current source is determined by the rest of the circuit. And you can never, ever talk about the "equivalent series resistance" of an ideal current source. However, in a case like this it allows you to determine one of the currents in the circuit by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers here.  When trying to figure out circuit equations, one can write all sorts of true facts.  The trick is to determine a minimum set of equations that will tell you all you need to know about the circuit, without writing more equations than you need. This is where “textbook learning” comes in handy. Two great techniques that answer this problem are 1. Nodal analysis, and 2. Mesh (or loop) analysis. If you use these techniques, you will never go wrong. However, you can often get confused or make errors if you just start writing down equations willy-nilly.